# If I turn my github repo to private, will the cloud project associated with it face any problems?

Tags: github, ibm-cloud

I have an active IBM Cloud app that is built on a GitHub repository. If I switch the access of that repo from public to private, will my web application face any problems?

Answer (score 0):

> will my web application face any problems?

Not as long as the IBM Cloud app is using a private SSH key or a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) which authenticate as the owner of that (now) private repository.